# Encrypting using FileVault on an Apple original SSD - any likely problems?

Tags: ssd, filevault

*There are plenty of FileVault 2 and SSD (Solid State Disk) questions on many forums, and a few already on this site, but this is more specific and I cannot find it even asked - let alone answered:*

**If the disk is a factory fitted, original Apple SSD (in a Macbook in my case) is there any possible down-side to encrypting the disk with FileVault (on Mavericks so I'm assuming version 2!)?**

Sure there may be a fractional (unnoticeable) performance overhead but apart from that, are there any disk wear-levelling issues (due to problems with TRIM perhaps)?

Ideally some documentation from Apple would be the best confirmation... if they have published any that I haven't found.

Answer (score 1):

I recently did some research on this topic because I want to install an SSD in my Macbook as well.
In my case it would not be a factory fitted one but I doubt that there are big technical differences between original Apple SSDs and custom ones, apart from TRIM being available by default vs. enabling TRIM on my own with a custom SSD.

The most satisfying answer I could find was this [discussion in the Apple Support Community](https://discussions.apple.com/message/16997991#16997991).
The interesting posting basically says that a user tested random sectors on a FileVault2 encrypted SSD and found some that were indeed empty (all zero). In a similar scenario on a classic magnetic HDD no empty sectors were found.
The user concludes that this means that unused sectors remain empty on SSDs and that TRIM will correctly work with FileVault2.

The conclusion seems reasonable to my understanding and after installing my SSD I personally will use FileVault2 in good conscience.
However, this is not an official answer from Apple and therefore should be treated with care.

Comment: That is very interesting and reassuring to know thanks audioPhil! It certainly sounds like it's avoiding wear-levelling issues somehow. On a side note; from experience with SSDs in PCs, different manufacturer's drives may or may not "play nicely" with the rest of the hardware/OS setup in a given machine. But it sounds like you've not got any issues in this case. I'd also assume Apple have it setup optimally for the SSDs they include from new.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I've noticed a drop of SSD speed, about 10mb/sec witch is **measurable however not noticeable**, except during boot up. a encrypted drive takes longer too boot. however the speeds of an SSD is so fast that its still *considerably* faster than a HDD!

*I don't know if the following is true* however I've read that sense FireVoult 2 encrypts the whole drive as apposed to the home directory it **encrypts and decrypts** everything **as you use** it, therefore it uses the disk more. and since a SSD gets slower and shows ware over time, this can have an impact on the long run.

I have myself not noticed any issues except those mentioned

Comment: 10mb a second when I see about 900mb a second certainly isn't noticeable and that's what I meant in the question - that's a known overhead and unavoidable. And yes - it is correct that FileVault 2 encrypts the whole partition.